# WIndows 11: Is it possible to run Powershell command as Administrator on Startup?

Tags: powershell, windows-11, administrator

I've just installed Windows 11, and I'm using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) for package management. For this, I would like to run an auto-upgrade of applications when Windows is starting up.

So at startup, I need to run a Powershell with Administrator privileges, that runs the following command:

```
choco upgrade -y all
```

It could be a shortcut with Administrator rights, that runs:

```
powershell -noexit -command "choco upgrade -y all"
```

I did already try to put a shortcut inside the "Startup" menu (`C:\Users\<my_user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`), and set it to "Run as Administrator", but it seems the shortcut does not execute at startup, and I'm not presented with the UAC prompt to confirm. I can click the shortcut manually from file explorer, and then it runs.

I've installed Powershell 7 along with the default Powershell 5. It doesn't really matter which one runs this.

Main reason I'm asking here is that it didn't "just work" as I expected. Any bright ideas?

Comment: since choco.exe isn't a powershell script, have you *tried* running it either directly or by calling cmd.exe?  as in `cmd.exe /c choco upgrade -y all` ?  Powershell is locked down in ways that cmd.exe is not.  I am not saying it will work.. I am saying it will *probably* work.

Comment: It is my understanding that `choco` requires to be run in Powershell, since it uses Powershell to do its thing. But I'm new to Chocolatey as well..

Comment: It's worth a shot.  Most exes don't work this way (relying on a scripting host).  If the exe REQUIRES powershell, then it will probably load the environment as it needs it.  I mean "why not try?" :)

Comment: Sure - I'll give it a try. If this is true, I should be able to go even further, and just make a shortcut that runs `choco upgrade -y all` directly, right? Why even invoke `cmd.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to put the actual script file in the startup folder?
try in all users folder too :
`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`

1. First try to add a simple batch file that opens notepad for exemple or calc :

   ```
   @echo off
   powerShell "c:\windows\system32\calc.exe"
   exit
   ```

   if it worked then just replace the **calc** path with your **powershell** script path
2. If the above not working

   - Open `taskschd.msc` in the Run prompt
   - Create a new Task
   - Select Run only when the user is logged on,
   - And check Run with Highest Privileges
   - After that name it and go to the Actions tab click new
   - Type powershell in the program/script input and your command in the Add arguments and ok
   - In the Triggers tap click new and choose **at log on** then clock ok
   - Log out and log in, it should work without rebooting if not reboot.

Comment: It's not a script - I just want to run a command. I'll try and troubleshoot some more when I get home later.

Comment: Oh i see but i think that you need to put that command in a powershell file (.ps1) to be located in the Task Scheduler to work in proper way
but you can try in the action tab to put your command like this
type powershell  in the program/script input
and your command in the Add arguments and ok
and before rebooting right click on the task and choose run to see if it worked